# How to invoke windows 'move' CLI from TCL program

Tags: tcl

I am using TCL on a Windows 7 machine. And I need to invoke the Windows `move` command via `exec`. However I cannot get it to work.

I am aware that TCL has the `file rename` ability, but for reasons I cannot get into I'm being asked to use the Windows `move` CLI.

When I use the `auto_execok` with move, that command returns an empty string. I've also tried with the {*} but it never works.

```
% info tclversion
8.6
%
% move src dest
invalid command name "move"
%
% [auto_execok move] src dest
ambiguous command name "": after append apply array auto_execok auto_import auto _load auto_load_index auto_qualify binary break case catch cd chan clock close c oncat continue coroutine dict encoding eof error eval exec exit expr fblocked fc onfigure fcopy file fileevent flush for foreach format gets glob global history if incr info interp join lappend lassign lindex linsert list llength lmap load l range lrepeat lreplace lreverse lsearch lset lsort namespace open package pid pr oc puts pwd read regexp regsub rename return scan seek set socket source split s tring subst switch tailcall tclLog tell throw time trace try unknown unload unse t update uplevel upvar variable vwait while yield yieldto zlib
%
```

I've also looked at the contents of the `auto_execok` command using the `info body auto_execok` and it almost looks like they didn't add 'move' to the list of suported commands....

Any suggestions on how to interface with the Windows `move` command from a TCL program?

Comment: Love to know the reasons for "cannot get into" :-).  One thing to be aware of with `file rename` and windows is that if there is just a filename case change (e.g. camelcase -> CamelCase), the -force flag is required: `file rename -force camelcase CamelCase`.

Answer (score 2):

Is `move` built into `cmd`? You might try:

```
exec {*}[auto_execok cmd] /c move src dest
```

I don't have a windows box to test with right now.

Comment: I think it is a built-in, and you'll need to make sure that src and dest are both converted to native names if they're not already.